# Is it possible for an element of a multiplicative group to have undefined order?

Tags: group-theory

This might be a stupid question but here it is:

Let $(G, \phi)$, where $\phi :G \times G \rightarrow G$, be a multiplicative group with identity element $e$. Then is it possible that $\exists a \in G$ such that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a^n \neq e$?

Another way to rephrase this is: Does every $a \in G$ generate a finite subgroup?

If you suppose that $\exists a \in G$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a^n \neq e$, and let $H=\left\{a^i:i \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ be the subgroup generated by $a$, then since the order of $a$ is the order of $H$, you get that the order of $H$ is either $0$ or infinite. If the order of $H$ is $0$, then $H= \emptyset$, which is a contradiction since $\emptyset$ is not a subgroup, hence $H$ must be infinite.

If $H$ is infinite,I don't see how this could produce a contradiction. It may be the case that $\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{N}$ such that $a^m = e$, or at least I cannot prove that this is an impossibility. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Cosnider the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. That is the group of integers under addition. There is no element with a finite order other than the identity itself $0$ and so consider

$1 + 1 + 1 + .......... \neq 0$ and so in general
$a + a + a + .............. \neq 0$ whenever $a \neq 0$

Comment: In any group , you only have one element that has order $1$ which is the identity

Comment: I am asking for multiplicative groups. I will fix the title. Thanks for your answers though.

Comment: @EthanRobinett: You're free to notate $(\mathbb Z,{+})$ with multiplicative notation if you want -- it's not an intrinsic property of a group whether it is "multiplicative" or "additive".

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Disregard that last comment. I was unaware of that. (I'm just learning group theory). Thanks

Comment: Of course... if your group is $(\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$, for instance, the identity element is $1$, and $2\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $2^n \neq 1$ for any $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, no element of a group has order $0$.  $o(e)=1$.  In $\Bbb Z$, $o(0)=1$ and $o(a)=\infty$ for any $a\ne0$.

Comment: Here, $G$ is multiplicative. $\mathbb{Z}$ under multiplication is not a group. (I assume here you are referring to $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition, I am asking for multiplicative groups)

Comment: Yes you are right, he is referring to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$

Comment: Fair enough, but my comments are still valid for any multiplicative group. See Henning Makholm's comment.

Answer (score 1):

consider the multiplicate group $\mathbb{Gl(2,R)}$ which is the group of $\color{red}{invertible}$ $2 \times 2$ matrices with the entries belonging to the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$

Clearly the identity is

$I =$$  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

However, if you consider the invertible matrix $\color{blue}{A =}$
 $ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

This one has infinite order since
 $\color{blue}{A^2 =}$
 $\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 2 \\ 
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

and   $\color{blue}{A^3 =}$
$ \begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 3 \\ 
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

and in general you have

$\color{blue}{A^n =}$
$\begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & n \\ 
    0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$

which is never equal to the identity matrix for all $n \geq 1$

Hope this answer your questions !